# How would I encrypt the entire user input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I'm trying to encrypt the inputted word of the user but it's only encrypting the last letter of that word.

In other words, If I input `abc` and click the button, the browser will display `z` instead of `xyz`.  It ignore the encryption of `ab`.

What am I doing wrong & how can I rectify this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show: false,
            encryptedValue: null
        };
    }

    encrypt = () => {
        let input = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
        let encryptedValue;

        let temp = "";

        for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            temp += input[i];

            switch(input[i].charAt(i)) {
                case "a":
                    encryptedValue = "x";
                    break;
                case "b":
                    encryptedValue = "y";
                    break;
                case "c":
                    encryptedValue = "z";
                    break;
                default:
                    encryptedValue = null;

            }
        }

        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = temp;

        this.setState({show: true, encryptedValue: encryptedValue});
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="type something" id="inputText"/>
                <button onClick={() => this.encrypt()}>Click to encrypt</button>
                <h1 id="res">{this.state.encryptedValue}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your `switch` statement you keep setting `encryptedValue` to an entirely *new* value instead of *appending* to your previous `encryptedValue`. In the case of `abc` it will only remember the last character you've encrypted, so `z`.

If you wanted to fix this issue change `=` to `+=` so it appends to `encryptedValue` instead of overriding it.

It also appears that you're switching over `input[i].charAt(i)` which is causing an error because `input[i]` already contains the character you want to switch.

```js
let input = "abc";
let encryptedValue = "";

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

  switch (input[i]) {
    case "a":
      encryptedValue += "x";
      break;
    case "b":
      encryptedValue += "y";
      break;
    case "c":
      encryptedValue += "z";
      break;
    default:
      encryptedValue += "";

  }
}

console.log(encryptedValue);
```

Comment: Wow... All I had to do was remove `charAt(i)` when I used += before.  It's always the tiny stuff that I miss.  Thanks a lot, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the string to a new value in each case, rather than appending a character to it.
For starters you can try += instead of = 
This will work for abc, but if you input obc, you'll only get yz.

To make it work for all cases, copy the original string into encryptedValue 1st, then set encryptedValue[i] to the encrypted character in each case

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the "encryptedValue" the encrypted string you should concatenate to it, so it should be

```
encryptedValue=encryptedValue+"x";
```

or a shorter version

```
encryptedValue+="x";
```

You could also use the encryption import in react
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-encrypt
It has simple functions like "encrypt(string)".